# Sort array error with Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm getting data from my server using `AFNetworking` and i'm sorting a json array like so:

```
func comparator(a: Dictionary, b: Dictionary) -> Bool {
    let first: String = a["type_name"] as String!
    let sec: String = b["type_name"] as String!
    if (first == sec) {
        let first_type: String = a["name"] as String!
        let sec_type: String = b["name"] as String!
        return first_type < sec_type
    }
    return first < sec
}
var initialArray = jsonDictionary["VALUES"] as Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>
var docArray = sorted(initialArray, comparator)
```

This works PERFECTLY when I run the app on my iPhone in debug mode (compiling through xcode). But when I do it via Testflight, app store, or adhoc deployment it crashes. I tried to do some debugging with it and turns out the sorting is where the error is coming from. The stack trace i'm getting from adhoc and app store (using Appsee) is:

```
_TTSGVSs26UnsafeMutableBufferPointerGVSs10DictionarySSPSs9AnyObject___GS_GS0_SSPS1____Ss21MutableCollectionType_GVSs28UnsafeBufferPointerGeneratorGS0_SSPS1____GS3_GS0_SSPS1____Ss13GeneratorType_GS0_SSPS1____SiSiSs21RandomAccessIndexType_SiSiSs18_SignedIntegerType_SiSiSs33_BuiltinIntegerLiteralConvertible_SiSiSs16SignedNumberType_SiSiS7__Si_GS0_SSPS1______TFSs14_introSortImplUSs21MutableCollectionType_USs13GeneratorType__Ss21RandomAccessIndexType_Ss18_SignedIntegerType_Ss33_BuiltinIntegerLiteralConvertible_Ss16SignedNumberType_S3_____FTRQ_GVSs5RangeQQ_5Index_RFTQQQ_9Generator7ElementS8__SbSi_T_
```

When I remove the sorting above by doing this:

```
var docArray = jsonDictionary["VALUES"] as Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>
```

The adhoc deployed app works perfectly fine. What is the reason for the above error? How is it that my sorting is fine in debug mode but not in any release mode of the app?? I'm absolutely stuck on this!

I thoroughly read Apple's documentation on this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html

Comment: What happens if you do this in Release versus Debug mode? Does it still not crash? Do you know if the a value exists for "VALUES" in jsonDictionary? Also, what if it is not an Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>? Since you are down casting using as, it will crash if it isn't the right type. If you can hook up to console while running the adhoc or TF build, you should be able to put in some println to see if the issue is no value for the key or wrong type of the downcast

Comment: Does this still happen to you? It believe it to be a optimisation bug in the compiler, which is why it happens only in release builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is a bug with `Swift`, otherwise I have no clue why this is so. Previously I had the `comparator` function defined in the success block for `AFNetworking`. I removed it from there and had it as a method for the class and somehow that fixed it. I'm not sure why this is a fix because I've done similar things in other parts of my code and it worked regardless.